# Is there any way to keep line breaks in a textarea (php)?

Tags: php

I have this script

```
<?php
include 'theme.php';
/*ceklogin();*/
css();
if($_POST['wget-send'])
    {
        $dir=$_POST['dir'];
        $link=$_POST['link'];
        exec('echo '.$link.' > /tmp/wget-download-link.txt',$out);
        exec('wget -P '.$dir.' -b -i /tmp/wget-download-link.txt -o /www/wget.log -c -t 100 -w 10',$out);
        echo $out[2];
        exit();
    }
echo "<br><br><form action=\"".$PHP_SELF."\" method=\"post\">";
echo "Download directory :<br><input type=\"text\" name=\"dir\" size=\"15\" value=\"/mnt/usb/\"/><br>";
echo '<br>Download link :<br>';
echo ("<textarea name=\"link\" rows=\"11\" cols=\"60\"></textarea><br><br>");
echo '<input type="submit" name="wget-send" value="Send" />';
echo "</form></div>";

foot();
echo '
</div>
</body>
</div>
</html>';
?></div>
</html>';
?>
```

Whenever I type in texts with two lines or more they won't be saved in `/tmp/wget-download-link.txt`. The file is always empty but when I only type in a text that consists only one line it's saved there. I'd like my `wget-download-link.txt` file to be like this:

```
http:xxx1
http:xxx2
http:xxx3
```

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: quote the $link while echo .. btw, why don't you use a php function file_put_contents() or fwrite to do this?

Comment: I'm sorry but can you elaborate it ? I don't get it

Answer (score 1):

You need to use "\n" to put a newline into your string.

Comment: like this?
`http:xxxx1 \n http:xxx2 \n http:xxx3`

it's a pain in the neck to do that, I'd like to avoid writing that and just click enter on my keyboard

Answer (score 0):

The new line character with the echo command is "\n". Taking the following example:

`echo  "This is line 1\nThis is line 2" > /tmp/hallo_world.txt`

so for you should work

```
exec('echo "'.$link.'" > /tmp/wget-download-link.txt',$out);
```

Before doing this you should **$link** replace \r\n in \n and mask doublequoats in $link content ....

Comment: can you please rewrite my code above? I'm still learning, I've tried your suggestion above but still `wget-download-link.txt` is empty when I type in some texts with line breaks

Comment: oh sorry, I didn't read your answer very carefully, been up for too long hehe, thank you very much, it works :D